# Can't get newline to print with ARM Linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, system-calls

I started with code from a Raspberry Pi assembly language book.  It prints out 15 in binary as so:

```
00000000000000000000000000001111pi@raspberrypi:$
```

I wanted to add a newline at the end, so I implemented the `_newline:` and `new: .ascii "\n"` portion of the code.

I reassembled it, but the output remains the same. Did I miss something in outputting the newline?

```
        .global _start
_start:
        mov r6, #15  
        mov r10, #1
        mov r9, r10, lsl #31
        ldr r1, =string
_bits:
        tst r6, r9
        moveq r0, #48
        movne r0, #49
        str r0, [r1]
        mov r8, r6
        bl _write
        mov r6, r8

        movs r9, r9, lsr #1
        bne _bits

_newline:
        mov r0, #1
        mov r2, #1
        mov r7, #4
        ldr r1, =new
        swi 0

_exit:
        mov r7, #1
        swi 0  
_write:
        mov r0, #1
        mov r2, #1
        mov r7, #4
        swi 0
        bx lr

.data
string: .ascii " "
new:    .ascii "\n"
```

---

The last few lines of strace output are:

```
write(1, "1", 11) = 1
write(1, "1", 11) = 1
write(1, "1", 11) = 1
write(1, "1", 11) = 1
write(1, "\0", 11) = 1
exit(1) =?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Try using `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls your process makes.

Comment: Also, I would have implemented this by writing the characters to a 17 byte buffer, with a newline at the end.  Store ASCII 0 or 1 into the buffer, then write it with a single system call, instead of calling `write()` separately for each byte.  Still, your way works, it's just less efficient.

Comment: The last few lines of strace gave me this:
write(1, "1", 11)      = 1
write(1, "1", 11)      = 1
write(1, "1", 11)      = 1
write(1, "1", 11)      = 1
write(1, "\0", 11)      = 1
exit(1)                    =?
+++ exited with 1 +++

Comment: I'm barely learning arm assembly so I just followed the book example, but I'll look into your way as well.

Comment: I added your strace output to your question, like you should have instead of posting it as a comment.  At least you picked the right part of the strace output to include. :)  It led me to the solution in about 10 seconds: I just had to ask: what could overwrite the `\n` with a `\0`?  Then look back at the other store, since I knew it was storing to adjacent data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strace output is the clue:  `write(1, "\0", 11) = 1` shows us that you wrote a 0 byte instead of the ASCII encoding of `\n`.

---

When you `str r0, [r1]`, you're storing 4 bytes.

The destination of that store is

```
.data
string: .ascii " "
new:    .ascii "\n"
```

which is really:

```
.data
string: .byte   ' '
new:    .byte   '\n'
```

So each time you store `'0'` or `'1'` to `string`, you're also writing 3 more zero bytes, clobbering your `'\n'` and 2 more bytes beyond the end of your data section.  (It doesn't segfault because you're not right at the end of a page.)

---

The simplest fix is to use a single-byte store: `strb r0, [r1]` instead of the word-sized `str`.

Comment: Thanks it works. How you explained it make so much sense.

Comment: @MarcoLugo: I'm glad it helped.  :)  Proper explanations are what SO is all about, IMO, not just code dumps.  That's why we like good questions with only one issue, that can lead to good answers that might be useful to other people in the future.